# Difference between db.collection.insert({name:"Xyz"}) and db.MyDatabase.insert({name:"Xyz"})

Tags: mongodb

I have created a database by the following command:

```
use MyDatabase
```

I want to know what is the difference between 
db.collection.insert({name:"Xyz"}) and db.MyDatabase.insert({name:"Xyz"})

Is there a "collection" database which is created and used by default ?

Comment: `collection` in `db.collection` is not database name. it's a collection name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mongodb, we can create a database just like we create in mysql and in mongodb after creating a database we can create a collection which is like tables in mysql ...we can create collection  by using the following command-

```
db.createCollection("collection_name");
```

In each collection we can insert data using the command-

```
db.collection_name.insertOne({name:"XYZ"});
```

the above command is anonymous to adding a row in the table.

Therefore answering your question -

You first created a database called myDatabase which created a myDatabase and when u do `db.collection.insert();`
Mongodb automatically creates a collection having the name "collection" and is present in the myDatabase database...
And when u do `db.Mydatabase.insert()` again another collection is created having name "Mydatabase"...
Hence basically your final result is a database named MyDatabase having two collections-

1. collection
2. Mydatabase

You can check the two collections create by using command-

```
 show collections;
```

Answer (score 0):

"collection"s are inside a "database"

`db` is `MyDatabase`

`collection` in `db.collection.insert(...)` is your collection name